# ASP.NET TableCell easy location

Tags: asp.net, cell

I've written a small chunk of code that creates a Table based on a two-dimensional Boolean array (the size of the array varies, so a fixed-size Table is not an option).

It is all nice and working, at least was, until I tried to add row- and column-specific calculations to the specific Cells. What I want to do is the following: on click, set a field to "Selected", change Cell background color, and add the cell's coordinates (row and column number) to an existing List.

Now, the problem is, that I found no way to get the Row and Column number of a given Cell. Is there any specific way to do so, apart from running a scan any time the Table changes, and comparing each Cell to its previous state?

Comment: Any code you can show us?

Comment: When you interact with a control within a cell you should be able to get at the sender of the event (the control at this point) and then get at the parent cell which would allow you to modify it.

Comment: Solved it in the meantime, gonna post an answer in a moment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set Server Side OnClick() event Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656855/set-server-side-onclick-event-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

So, the easiest solution was actually found on StackOverflow, in a different question:
[Set Server Side OnClick() event Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656855/set-server-side-onclick-event-programmatically)

As I had to write some functions over the existing TableCell class, the easiest was to add two extra properties - one int for Row, and another for Column. Now any time I'm accessing the cells of the table, I can call their Column and Row properties, and get them in a whiffy.